# Migrating from OneSignal to FoxPush push notifications

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

Really try to search many different type on Google, but not really good answers, i found.

Also , i found an  article ; https://www.izooto.com/blog/migrate-different-web-push-notification-platform

and there is some info on, FoxPush knowledge base. : https://support.foxpush.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014649132-Can-I-import-my-list-of-subscribers-from-another-vendor-in-case-I-decide-to-move-to-FoxPush-

It means;

If i upload FoxPush setup files, on my root directory , it can sync my all users to their system ? Thats it ?

Should i put some codes on my header file or not ?

Any suggest ?

Many thanks.

Comment: hey, any updates :(